# ¿Se puede hacer listas infinitas en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

tengo una duda para un programa que quiero hacer.

El programa quiere separar una frase en palabras, introduciendo una palabra en cada índice de una lista.

```
im = str(input("Introduce la frase: "))

def separar_(em):
    lista = []
    a = 0
    for i in em:
        if i == " ":
            a += 1
            lista[a] = ""
        else:
            lista[a] += i
    return lista

print(separar_(im))
```

El programa da este error: IndexError: list index out of range

Mi pregunta es ¿puedo hacer una lista con infinitos índices, o sea, no que tenga 100000 de índices, sino que, mediante la ejecución del programa se pueda añadir más índices.

Comment: Por que no usas los métodos append (insertar un elemento al final de la lista) o insert (insertar un elemento en una posicion especifica de la lista) de las listas? Esta pagina habla sobre estos métodos https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-list-python/#list-add

Comment: No necesitas recorrer la lista buscando espacios. Ya hay un método que hace eso. Usa `em.split()` y va a devolverte una lista de las palabras de tu frase, da igual lo grande que sea. En el caso que quieras añadir más palabras usa el método `append()` de una lista. Trata de investigar un poco más. No tiene mucho sentido lo que preguntas.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta "¿Se puede hacer listas infinitas en python?", la respuesta es NO, por que no hay capacidad de memoria  infinita para guardar una lista.

Comment: Lo bueno de python es que es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico lo que hace que no se tenga que especificar el tipo de dato y tampoco declarar el tamaño de una lista (a diferencia de lenguajes como C, java, C#, etc), por lo que **nunca** vas a declarar el tamaño y **siempre** se van agregando en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: @Christian depende tu definicion de lista, en java y c# no tienen un tamaño predeterminado y serian tan grandes como quieras... en C.. dependiendo tu implementacion, tambien...

Comment: @gbianchi en esos lenguajes serían arrays, dije listas refiriéndome a python ya que en este no existen los arrays y su equivalencia en otro lenguaje es el array.

Comment: @Christian no.. en todos esos lenguajes que nombraste, existen arrays (conjuntos de datos metidos en partes subsecuentes de memoria) y listas (conjunto de nodos en posiciones de memoria dispersas). Existen las dos cosas, y son dos cosas distintas. Dijiste listas. y los array en todos esos lenguajes son redimensionables, con el costo de movimiento de datos en memoria que corresponde...

Comment: @gbianchi en python no existe el tipo de dato `array` existe `list`, si bien `numpy` simula uno, no es un tipo de dato nativo de python. En los otros lenguajes claro que existe

Comment: El error es pensar que `lista[i] = x` **crea** el elemento *i-esimo* en la lista. Eso no es correcto: arroja el error que muestras. La asignación `lista[i] = x` sólo funciona como reemplazo, es decir, si ya existe el elemento *i-esimo* en la lista. Para agregar un elemento a una lista, usada el método `lista.append(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

El método `split(separador)` divide una cadena en partes separadas por `separador` y la devuelve como lista. Si omites el argumento, divide donde encuentras *white-spaces* (espacios, tabuladores, nueva linea, ...).

```
i = 1000
im = str(input("Introduce la frase: "))

print(im.split())
```

produce:

```
Introduce la frase: la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta
['la', 'mona', 'jacinta', 'se', 'ha', 'puesto', 'una', 'cinta']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

He visto que ya hay varias soluciones, pero dejo por aquí la mía.
La solución que he preparado es para realizar una simulación de la función `split()`, donde se concatena letra por letra hasta llegar a los espacios en blanco.

```
im = str(input("Introduce la frase: "))
def separar_(em):
    lista = []
    texto = ""
    for i in em:
        if i != " ":  # concatena si no hay espacio
            texto = texto + i
        else:
            lista.append(texto)
            texto = ""
    lista.append(texto)  # lo añade cuando termine el bucle
    return lista
print(separar_(im))
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.